# how to access phone book contacts?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

I am using an Edittext and a button . On press of a button , phone book gets open and then user will select a contact from it and the selected phonenumber will get display on the edittext.
I followed many tutorials and but the methods that they are showing are already depreciated.

I have declared this permission: READ_CONTACTS in manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_picker);

        // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        // and the intent.setType
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pick_person)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
            }
        });
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    int type = c.getInt(1);
                    showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
    Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}
```

Comment: do i have to declare any other permission other than READ_CONTACTS

Comment: done .. but its not showing the selected contact on the edittext just the toast

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Digvesh Patel is correct. He has used "type" of contact, which returns number. so I have used his code and made some changes which i used in my application. it maybe helpful to someone

```
public int REQUESTCODE=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select);
    select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.i("data", uri.toString());
        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(0);
                    String number = c.getString(1);
                    int type = c.getInt(2);

                    showSelectedNumber(name, number,type);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(String name,  String number, int type){
    TextView usernumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String typelabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
    usernumber.setText(name+": "+number+" "+typelabel);

}
```